# Error, InvalidLong / Number format exception

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I am developing an app where I pass values to a list using ListAdapter and one of the values is a String and I parse it to int value. Code snippet for adapter class is shown below

```
 public long getItemId(int i) {
        return Long.parseLong(list.get(i).getProductID().trim());
    }
```

However I am able to view the list passed, but once I touch the screen (sometimes once or multiple times - no issues while scrolling the list) I get a NumberformatException error due to which my app crashes. **Below is the error log**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1101V0104"
    at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
    at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:361)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
    at com.example.knr.DataListAdapter.getItemId(DataListAdapter.java:44)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(AdapterView.java:769)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.setSelectedPositionInt(AdapterView.java:1154)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3623)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3436)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
```

Is there any other way in order to avoid this error so that my app wont crash? Thank you!!

Comment: As you can see in your long value is "1101V0104" in this number 'V' is not number and you are casting in to long try to see long ID in DB or where it comes

Comment: This "1101V0104" is the value which is the only value which is in my list obtained from the server. The other values are long. So to avoid this I parsed it to long and tried to execute. I did this because the getItemID in the adapter class only returns long and I cannot change it to any other type. So I asked if there is any other method of parsing this value.

Comment: ohk put break point at return Long.parseLong(list.get(i).getProductID().trim()); and try to debug what you are getting from server ?

Comment: The values for example which I get from server are 194701, 194702 etc. which are valid long. However, this one value 1101V0104 isn't a valid long. But I need to return this value to my list. Is there anyway by which I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: its not compulsory to return your ID you can return 0 also but its not good practice so please tell me 1101V0104 from where come in picture? as you say you get proper long number from server so whats return getProductID() method??

Comment: Well here is my getProudctId() method..  

public String getProductID() {
        return ProductID;
    }

    public void setProductID(String productID) {
        ProductID = productID;
    }

The value 1101V0104 is the only exception value which is coming from the server. Other values coming in are correct. So I parse this as Long and send it to my adapter/fragment to display the list.. I need to know how to achieve this without getting a number format exception!

Comment: yes ,ou are right  have debug your program ?? ok let me give you sniped so you can avoid this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when ever you don't sure about value getting from server try to check it and after perform operation on it like casting

```
 public long getItemId(int i) {
  if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(list.get(i).getProductID().toString())        
     return Long.parseLong(list.get(i).getProductID());
  else
     return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the logcat output itself.

This line : java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1101V0104"

You are trying to get a Long out of something that is, well, not a Long.

Comment: True, I do this because other numbers from where I am getting these values are Long.This particular entry alone is the only exception.

Comment: The comment is useful, but do you know any ways to overcome and parse it as long, since my other dependent values are of long.. thanks!!